# This device type does not match the module profile. Error while Deploying HAP

Tags: debugging, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I've set up HUAWEI [DevEco Studio](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/tools_overview-0000001053582387) with HarmonyOS SDK, but fail to launch a newly created project:

[image: Screenshot]

I'd suppose, that this might be a phone module, but I have tablet hardware.

How I can change that - or which modules are suitable for a "large screen"?

Answer (score 3):

I've found it myself; the relevant configuration file is: `entry/src/main/config.json`.

`"deviceType": ["phone"]` should be `"deviceType": ["tablet"]`. One can even combine them: `"deviceType": ["phone", "tablet"]` (there seem to be Phone, Tablet, TV, Wearable, Car). Then it fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_BUNDLE_SIGNATURE`, but this wasn't the question.

Comment: Are you facing this while deploying to simulator? @Martin, In case you use hardware (real device) you have to sign your hap before deploying. For signing refer this blog - https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201556815764790264

Comment: @GowthamGS I can run on hardware, when I first run `adb kill-server` (to close previous connections). The local emulator says that it is "Lite" and refuses to boot.